# Print statement creates an unwanted newline

Tags: python, python-3.x, newline

I am trying to go through a long list of words, and print both the lowercase word and the uppercase word (default) to the screen in the same line. Here is my code:

```
for word in word_list:

    print("Here is: {0} and {1}".format(word.lower(), word))
```

However, this has the output (showcasing only two words):

```
Here is: word1 
 and WORD1

Here is: word2 and WORD2
```

I have not been able to get rid of the newline between word1 and WORD1. It does not appear to happen for the last word I try and print. Any ideas as to why, and how to overcome this?

Comment: using `word.strip()`?

Comment: so the value of `word` is `'WORD1\n'`, not `'WORD1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example to reproduce your issue:

```
In [1411]: word = 'WORD1\n'

In [1412]: print("Here is: {0} and {1}".format(word.lower(), word))
Here is: word1
 and WORD1
```

Notice the trailing newline. One of your list elements has those. You can remove it using [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

```
In [1413]: word = word.strip(); print("Here is: {0} and {1}".format(word.lower(), word))
Here is: word1 and WORD1
```

You can also use [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip), (`r` => right) if there's only the possibility of *trailing* whitespace chars (not leading ones).

On a related note, I'd recommend taking a look at [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you very much!